# UIScrollView and issue setting UIPageControl's current page

Tags: ios, ios6, uiscrollview

I am trying to setup a UIPageControl and need to set the `currentPage`; I have the following but once the value is assigned self.pageControl.currentPage, it always equals 0 even though it should be a correct value. This is my first time using UIPageControl and I think I am missing something really basic; possibly always being reset to 0 somewhere. thx in advance

Here's my code

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
    self.pageControl.currentPage = (int) floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x + 0.25)/320.0f);
    int this_page=(int)(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x + 0.25)/320.0f;
  self.pageControl.currentPage=this_page;
  NSLog(@"here is property %d", self.pageControl.currentPage);
  NSLog(@"here is this_page %d", this_page);
  self.pageControl.currentPage=4;
  NSLog(@"here is property after manual set %d", self.pageControl.currentPage);

}
```

and my NSLog output.

```
2013-03-03 10:19:14.204 Lt[32045:11303] here is property 0
2013-03-03 10:19:14.206 Lt[32045:11303] here is this_page 1
2013-03-03 10:28:03.993 Lt[32209:11303] here is property after manual set 0
2013-03-03 10:19:15.449 Lt[32045:11303] here is property 0
2013-03-03 10:19:15.449 Lt[32045:11303] here is this_page 2
2013-03-03 10:28:03.993 Lt[32209:11303] here is property after manual set 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `self.pageControl` is nil, i.e. you never hooked up the outlet properly. Or else the page control itself isn't configured correctly, e.g. you never set `numberOfPages`.

BTW the easiest way to coordinate a page control with a paginating scroll view in iOS 6 is to use UIPageViewController instead.

Comment: yeah, I think you're right. manually setting doesn't update the pageControl value